# How to change threshold of "touchmove" in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, dom-events

I just want to ask if there is a way to change the threshold of the event `touchmove`? In my PhoneGap App, an image will appear. If `touchstart` is triggered, another image will appear. If `touchend` or `touchmove` is triggered, all images must disappear. Here is my code:

```
$('.greenApple').on('touchend', function (e){
    $('body').find('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('body').find('.greenApple').addClass('hidden');
    flag = true;
    return;
});

$('.greenApple').on('touchmove', function (e){
    $('body').find('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('body').find('.greenApple').addClass('hidden');
    flag = true;
    return;
```

However, the threshold of the number of pixels that is considered a `touchmove` is too little. Frequently, as soon as I press the image (not releasing it, `touchend` is not being triggered), the image disappears because the `touchmove` event is triggered. Is there a way to change the number of pixels of moved that is considered as `touchmove`? Or there are other workarounds?

Answer (score 4):

You need to modify this property

- $.vmouse.moveDistanceThreshold (default: 10px) – More than this, then it is a scroll event. The vmousecancel event is called and the TouchMove event is cancelled.

Try the code below:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
        $.vmouse.moveDistanceThreshold (default: 20px)
    });
</script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

Take a look at this [Official Documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/vmouseover/)

Comment: This answer looks promising. Can link where I can test it?

Comment: Take a look at this demo of the TouchSwipe plugin where you can play with the threshold distance.

http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Basic_swipe.html

Documentation for configuring the threshold distance are given in the link below. 

http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/docs/symbols/%24.fn.swipe.defaults.html

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the default behavior of the browser, but you can use the event data to filter out small movements that you want to suppress.  The `touch` attribute of the event parameter gives position information. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch) for full details.

Save the position on start and compare the position on touchmove. Remove the items from the page only if greater than the threshold that you set.

```
  var flag, x,y, distance = 25;

  $('.greenApple').on('touchstart', function (e){
    x = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX
    y = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageY

  });

  $('.greenApple').on('touchmove', function (e){
    var deltaX = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX - x;
    var deltaY = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageY - y;
    var difference = (deltaX * deltaX) + (deltaY * deltaY)
    if(Math.sqrt(difference) > distance) {
        $('body').find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('body').find('.greenApple').addClass('hidden');
        flag = true;
  });
```

Here's a [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xf0f3mgf/5/)

Comment: Hi @kindasimple. I tried that approach with the help from this fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/achudars/fq75t/`. However, this does not work with my project since I have 5 divs that share the `greenapple` class, and either the `active` or `hidden` class. The scenario is, a div pops up, touchstart is triggered and coordinate is stored. However, I still have 4 divs that must be able to store the touchstart coordinates, which this approach cant do. I can explain it in detail.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. You have a touch point array, so you have access to multiple touch points if you are interacting with multiple divs. You will just have to perform the distance calculation over the array instead of just the first touch point

Answer (score 1):

*need not find the class, if there is not and will not do anything wrong*

```
$('button').on('touchend', function (e){

/*no function whatsoever*/

    console.log($("body").find('.active').first().html());
    console.log($("body").find('.active').html());
/*only here*/
    console.log($("body").html());

/*just do it this way*/

    $('body').removeClass('active');
    $('body').addClass('hidden');
    flag = true;
    return;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Store last touch coordinates in element data and trigger `touchmove` handler only when their change is significant.

```
var treshold = 12345;    // set whatever treshold you like

function storeLastTouch (element, event) {
    element.data('lastTouch', event.originalEvent.changedTouches);
}

$('.greenApple').on('touchstart', function (event) {
    storeLastTouch($(this), event);
});

$('.greenApple').on('touchmove', function (event) {
    var lastTouch = $(this).data('lastTouch'),
        thisTouch = event.originalEvent.changedTouches,
        delta = ...;    // calculate difference in any metric you like
    if (delta > treshold) {
        storeLastTouch($(this), event);
        // ... (perform your handler logic)
    }
});
```